# AutoHotKey to focus a Form in Microsoft Access 2010/2013

Tags: ms-access-2010, autohotkey, ms-access-2013

I would like to use AutoHotKey to bring an access database to the screen, then take focus on one form (the form is open, but there will always be multiple other forms open at the same time, additionally, the form in question could be stacked at the bottom) and then the rest can be done with custom shortcuts that only work in this form.

I am also open for other solutions to do the same job, mouse clicks is also a possibility but forms are not always in the same place on different computers and they can also be moved during a session.

This is what I have been testing so far:

Bring up the database with `IfWinExist, [title of window]`

Then I tried using `ControlFocus, [ControllerName]`

That did work, but the controllername changes depending on what other forms are open and in which order they where last clicked on.

I have made a screenshot:

[image]

Any help would be nice, my main problem is that I do not know what AHK can do and therefore I feel very limited.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Access forms but I imagine they contain some kind of coding (maybe VBA?). Can you manipulate the code in order to make your own shortcuts or even eliminate the need to use AHK?

Comment: You could try creating an application-wide [AutoKeys macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/run-an-access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-HA010239111.aspx) in Access that uses `RunCode` to execute some VBA. The VBA code could activate the appropriate Access form or take the appropriate action. Then all AHK would need to do is activate (bring forward) the Access application and then fire the keyboard shortcut at it. (I'm really just guessing here.)

Comment: Thanks MCL and Gord, that would off course work, the problem is that i am not the developer of this access database, so any changes i do the the VBA will be overwritten on the next update.

I do like the idea, and it is no problem doing this in VBA and having AHK trigger the VBA code. 

I will wait and see if a different solution comes, if not i will try it.

I am using AHK in a different application to get the search string that is going to be used in the access form, so i do need to use AHK.

Comment: What about sequences of arrow/TAB/Enter keystrokes? Btw: "The form you want to focus" in your screenshot (pointing to the Window Spy entry) isn't really a GUI element per se. Under "Visible window text", Window Spy simply lists all the text in the window (like edits, buttons, captions etc.) which you will most likely not be able to interact with. Furthermore, mouse clicks are relative to the receiving window by default in AHK, so different positioning wouldn't be a problem, as long as the form has its own window with position and dimensions.

Comment: You are locked inside every Form, you can change with the keyboard but then i would have to find out when i get to the right Form, that could be a possibility.  Relative mouse clicks could actualy work, i did knot know about this. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

In the place of WinTitle you can also use other parameters of the window, not only WinTitle. More about it here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm

Also you can use [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) to get coordinates of the window and use these coordinates to move window without [WinMove](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) like here: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4013

Comment: I will look into it and give feedback in a few days.